# Unable to perform RBAC for vCenter

Tags: permissions, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, rbac

I have added the vCenter to the AD, and I am able to retrieve groups. We have a Datacenter which has about 7 ESXi hosts. I'd like to slice these hosts, in such a way that a few users are granted access to only a few hosts when they login to vCenter.

[image]

I've shown what the schema looks like. I would like users to receive Admin privileges ONLY on the ESXi host that they've been granted access to. To do this, I have done the following:

1. On top most `gspsec-vcenter`, I added the user and given Admin privilege but `Propagate to Child Objects` is unchecked.
2. On `GSPSEC` datacenter, I added the user and given Admin privilege but `Propagate to Child Objects` is unchecked.
3. On `Cluster` cluster, I added the user and given Admin privilege but `Propagate to Child Objects` is unchecked.
4. On `HOST` ESXi host, I added the user and given Admin privilege but `Propagate to Child Objects` is **checked**.

So, on the host itself, I have granted admin privilege but I am still unable to see any VMs at all when I login with that user id.

Please assist.

Comment: Have you looked at the permissions on one of the VM's?

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the problem. So, even though I click `propagate for child objects` for the ESXi host, the VMs themselves don't see that the user was defined on a level above. But, in case I define `propagate for child objects` on the the `Cluster` I can see the user on the VM permissions as well. Why is this happening?

Comment: I see the same problem even if using the vSphere Web Client.

Comment: (Bump, no reply for 3 days)

Comment: Still no answers?